# minikube start - howto modify KubeletConfiguration passed to kubeadm?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, kubeadm, kubelet

I would like to set the value `KubeletConfiguration.cpuCFSQuota = false` in the `config.yaml` passed to `kubeadm` when launching `minikube` to turn off CPU resource checking, but I have not managed to find the options to do this through the documentation here https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/config/ .  The closest solution I have found is to use the option `--extra-config=kubelet.cpu-cfs-quota=false` but the `--cpu-cfs-quota` option for the `kubelet` has been deprecated and no longer  has an effect.

Any ideas appreciated.

Environment:

- Ubuntu 20.04
- Minikube 1.17.1
- Kubernetes 1.20.2
- Driver docker (20.10.2)

Thanks,
Piers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `--extra-config=kubelet.` flag alongside `minikube start` is a good approach but you would also need to [Set Kubelet parameters via a config file](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubelet-config-file/).

As you already noticed the `--cpu-cfs-quota` flag:

> Enable CPU CFS quota enforcement for containers that specify CPU
> limits (DEPRECATED: This parameter should be set via the config file
> specified by the Kubelet's `--config` flag.

So you need to set that parameter by creating a `kubelet` config file:

> The configuration file must be a JSON or YAML representation of the
> parameters in this struct. Make sure the Kubelet has read permissions
> on the file.
>
> Here is an example of what this file might look like:
>
> ```
> apiVersion: kubelet.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
> kind: KubeletConfiguration
> evictionHard:
>     memory.available:  "200Mi"
> ```

Now you can use that config file to set `cpuCFSQuota` = `false`:

```
// cpuCFSQuota enables CPU CFS quota enforcement for containers that
// specify CPU limits.
// Dynamic Kubelet Config (beta): If dynamically updating this field, consider that
// disabling it may reduce node stability.
// Default: true
// +optional`
CPUCFSQuota *bool `json:"cpuCFSQuota,omitempty"
```

and than call minikube with `--extra-config=kubelet.config=/path/to/config.yaml`

Alternately, you can start your minikube without the `--extra-config` flag and than [start the Kubelet with the `--config` flag](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubelet-config-file/#start-a-kubelet-process-configured-via-the-config-file) set to the path of the Kubelet's config file. The Kubelet will then load its config from this file.

I know these are a few steps more than you expected but setting the kubelet parameters via a config file is the recommended approach because it simplifies node deployment and configuration management.

Comment: Will that completely override any other configuration that minikube passes to kubeadm for the kubelet?  Would I need to capture that and add it in?

Comment: As stated in the docs: Command line flags which target the same value as a config file will override that value. Also, if `--config` is provided and the values are not specified via the command line, the defaults for the `KubeletConfiguration` version apply.